# Create a nested array of objects (up to 5 levels) from flat array of objects

Tags: javascript, antd

I need to create a nested array of objects from flat array of objects, which has up to 5 levels. The original JSON looks like this:

```
[{
  "code": "01",
  "name": "Some name 1",
  "level": "1"
}, {
  "code": "01.1",
  "name": "Some name 2",
  "level": "2"
}, {
  "code": "01.11",
  "name": "Some name 3",
  "level": "3"
}, {
  "code": "01.11.1",
  "name": "Some name 4",
  "level": "4"
}, {
  "code": "01.11.11",
  "name": "Some name 5",
  "level": "5"
}, {
  "code": "01.11.12",
  "name": "Some name 6",
  "level": "5"
}]
```

The new array will be used in Ant Design [Tree](https://ant.design/components/tree/) component, so it should have the following structure:

```
[
  {
    key: '01',
    title: 'Some name 1',
    children: [
      key: '01.1'
      title: 'Some name 2',
      children: [
        {
          key: '01.11'
          title: 'Some name 3',
          children: [
            {
              key: '01.11.1'
              title: 'Some name 4',
              children: [
                {
                  key: '01.11.11'
                  title: 'Some name 5'
                },
                {
                  key: '01.11.12'
                  title: 'Some name 6'
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

I have created a function for nesting the array, but the component becomes very slow. I guess there is a better way to do this. Here is my code:

```
const __getCodes = () => {
  let array = codeData;
  let result = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let obj = array[i];
    if (obj.level === "1") {
      result.push({key: obj.code, title: obj.code + ' ' + obj.name, checkable: false});
    }
    if (obj.level === "2") {
      const currentGroup = result.find(group => group.key === obj.code.substring(0,2))
      if (!currentGroup.children) {
        currentGroup.children = []
      }
      currentGroup.children.push({key: obj.code, title: obj.code + ' ' + obj.name, checkable: false})
    }
    if (obj.level === "3") {
      const parentGroup = result.find(group => group.key === obj.code.substring(0,2))
      const currentGroup = parentGroup.children.find(group => group.key === obj.code.substring(0,4))
      if (!currentGroup.children) {
        currentGroup.children = []
      }
      currentGroup.children.push({key: obj.code, title: obj.code + ' ' + obj.name})
    }
    if (obj.level === "4") {
      const subParentGroup = result.find(group => group.key === obj.code.substring(0,2))
      const parentGroup = subParentGroup.children.find(group => group.key === obj.code.substring(0,4))
      const currentGroup = parentGroup.children.find(group => group.key === obj.code.substring(0,5))
      if (!currentGroup.children) {
        currentGroup.children = []
      }
      currentGroup.children.push({key: obj.code, title: obj.code + ' ' + obj.name})
    }
    if (obj.level === "5") {
      const subSubParentGroup = result.find(group => group.key === obj.code.substring(0,2))
      const subParentGroup = subSubParentGroup.children.find(group => group.key === obj.code.substring(0,4))
      const parentGroup = subParentGroup.children.find(group => group.key === obj.code.substring(0,5))
      const currentGroup = parentGroup.children.find(group => group.key === obj.code.substring(0,7))
      if (!currentGroup.children) {
        currentGroup.children = []
      }
      currentGroup.children.push({key: obj.code, title: obj.code + ' ' + obj.name})
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const treeData = __getCodes();
```

How can I optimize this function to get the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a solution that will use `level` property to push current object at some level in the nested structure and combine that with references and `reduce` method.

```js
const data = [{"code":"01","name":"Some name 1","level":"1"},{"code":"01.1","name":"Some name 2","level":"2"},{"code":"01.11","name":"Some name 3","level":"3"},{"code":"01.11.1","name":"Some name 4","level":"4"},{"code":"01.11.11","name":"Some name 5","level":"5"},{"code":"01.11.12","name":"Some name 6","level":"5"}]

const result = data.reduce((r, { level, ...rest }) => {
  const value = { ...rest, children: [] }
  r[level] = value.children;
  r[level - 1].push(value)
  return r;
}, [[]]).shift()

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you very much  I just changed `const value = { key: code, title: name, children: [] }` for it to work with antd component. I have a question, how can I add `checkable: false` to objects at level 1 and 2?

Comment: @jupiteror You can just check if the level is < 3 and if so add the property https://jsfiddle.net/17mreqbk/1/

Comment: Thank you very much for such an elegant solution! It works great!